# adding items to deep List of KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, .net, list

I wrote a deep list:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>>>>> ListBoxes = new List<KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>>>>>();
```

Anybody has an idea how to add to this list any items?

For example:
`("A",LIST("B",LIST("C",true)))`

Comment: Instead of going so deep into a generics rabbit hole, why didn't you write a custom class that does _exactly_ what you need?

Comment: Or several, given that level of nesting it seems like you need more than one class.

Comment: Cause using so much classess seems that they require more ram than list of lists of lists :)

Comment: What are you using this for? I have a feeling that there may be a simpler solution than the data structure you're using.

Comment: You're using three-deep nested lists instead of a class ... to save memory?  That's crazy talk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy:

```
ListBoxes.Add(
    new KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>>>>("A",
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>>("B", 
                new List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>() {
                    new KeyValuePair<string,bool>("C", true)
                }
            )
        }
    )
);
```

It looks like you could use some helper methods or something.

**Edit**

If you create a simple extension method, then the task becomes maybe a bit more readable.

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> AddKVP<TKey, TValue>(this List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> self, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    self.Add(
        new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value)
    );

    // return self for "fluent" like syntax
    return self;
}

var c = new List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>().AddKVP("c", true);
var b = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>>>().AddKVP("b", c);
var a = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>>>>>().AddKVP("a", b);
```

**Edit #2**

If you define a simple type, then it helps a bit more:

```
public class KVPList<T> : List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> { }

public static KVPList<TValue> AddKVP<TValue>(this KVPList<TValue> self, string key, TValue value)
{
    self.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TValue>(key, value));
    return self;
}

var ListBoxes = new KVPList<KVPList<KVPList<bool>>>()
   .AddKVP("A", new KVPList<KVPList<bool>>()
       .AddKVP("B", new KVPList<bool>()
           .AddKVP("C", true)));
```

**Edit #3**

One more and I promise I'll stop.  If you define "Add" on the type, then you can use implicit initialization:

```
public class KVPList<T> : List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> 
{
    public void Add(string key, T value)
    {
        base.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,T>(key, value));
    }
}

var abc = new KVPList<KVPList<KVPList<bool>>> { 
    { "A", new KVPList<KVPList<bool>> {
        { "B", new KVPList<bool> {
            { "C", true }}
        }}
    }};
```